# Salesforce Validation Rule ensuring field contains no line breaks

Tags: validation, salesforce

I'm trying to write a data validation rule that ensures `Shipping Street` is one line (doesn't contain line breaks)

I've tried things like
`CONTAINS( ShippingStreet , BR() )`, and
`CONTAINS( ShippingStreet , "\n" )`,
but I can't get the rule to trigger.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
REGEX(ShippingStreet,'.*\\n.*')
```

There are 2 things to learn from this question about SFDC REGEX parsing:

(1) As per [Java SE 6 Pattern syntax](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you need to double-escape the new-line character (\n), along with various other special characters, when used in a *string* that gets compiled to a regular expression, that is, use '\n'.

(2) The Salesforce Regular Expression parser matches **the entire phrase** by default. To match on just part of the phrase, you have to surround your pattern with **.***

Examples:

```
 1. REGEX('Marc Benioff','Marc Benioff') -> TRUE
 2. REGEX('Marc Benioff is a CEO','Marc Benioff') -> FALSE
 3. REGEX('Marc Benioff','.*Marc Benioff.*') -> TRUE
 4. REGEX('Marc Benioff is a CEO','.*Marc Benioff.*') -> TRUE
```

For more info, read the 'Tips' section of the [SFDC REGEX Help docs](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?section=Customizing&target=customize_functions.htm#REGEX&loc=help).

Answer (score 0):

The following in a validation rule should mean that only ShippingStreet values containing characters only (and thereby no line breaks and the like) are accepted.

```
NOT(REGEX(ShippingStreet, '.*'))
```